# How to generate d.ts and d.ts.map files using webpack?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I can't find a way to generate d.ts and d.ts.map files using webpack. babel-loader only generates js and js.map files. I also need d.ts and d.ts.map files (which I was able to generate using `tsc` command) as shown in this picture:

[image]

Here is a minimal repo that contains all the settings: https://github.com/stavalfi/lerna-yarn-workspaces-example

### More Details

I moved to Lerna + yarn. One of my packages is `core` (will be used in other packages) which is written in TS and JS.

I'm using webpack 4,babel-loader 8 for ts-to-js.

The other packages are trying to find type definitions and implementation of my `core` package but I was only able to generate `index.js` and `index.js.map` with webpack:

```
output: {
    path: distPath,
    filename: 'index.js',
  },
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.settings.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "declarationDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist"
  }
}
```

- When I compile with `tsc` (without webpack), everything is working great as I showed in the picture above.

Does my strategy is wrong? what should I do?

---

I have tried a lot of plugins that generate d.ts files but they don't work and doesn't create `d.ts.map` files.

I already tried: `typescript-declaration-webpack-plugin`, `npm-dts-webpack-plugin`, `dts-bundle-webpack`, `@ahrakio/witty-webpack-declaration-files`. (They are listed in the package.json of `core` so you can clone and play with it).

Comment: From my understanding (read about 10min) babel doesn't actually compile your tsc, it just removes it all to plain js? So there's no way it's going to spit out type definitions for you? Seems like you would have to have webpack use ts-loader or something and then spit out your js files to be included by babel. (hopefully someone more familiar can answer your question with more certainty!)

Comment: You understood it right. I don't want to move to `ts-loader` because I need babel for all the packages code. I also edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running `ts-loader` before `babel-loader` will do the trick.

Specifying that you want declaration files in config is all you need.

---

If you are using an absolute path, the output d.ts files will also contain absolute paths which are useless and will result in typescript compilation errors.

To fix that, I wrote a plugin to convert an absolute path to a relative path: 
https://github.com/stavalfi/babel-plugin-module-resolver-loader

Comment: Instead of installing another loader (ts-loader), you can also add `'tsc'` at the end of your build command but you have configure your `ts.config` so it emits only the types declaration as shown here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/babel-with-typescript.html

Comment: I'm having the same issue but moving `ts-loader` up the loaders arrays to before `babel-loader` did not do anything. no `d.ts` or map files have been generated. Is this answer still valid?

Answer (score 2):

You can call the Typescript compiler `tsc` directly to do that.

Use `tsc --declaration` to output a `.d.ts` file and `tsc --declarationMap` to generate the corresponding map file.

You can find more documentation here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: I want to genrate them from webpack or else i will need to compile everything twice...

Comment: Eh, if Babel isn't actually compiling the ts for speed reasons I wouldn't consider this compiling twice

Comment: There is also "tsc --emitDeclarationOnly"

Comment: Hi, is it possible to generate specifically only the `.d.ts.map`? I am using Tsup that already spawns the .d.ts, but not yet the .d.ts.map